# express-http-context loses the context inside a database callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multi-tenant

We want to add multi tenancy support in our express (NodeJS) backed application. We chose express-http-context to propagate the tenant context to the child calls. We see a strange behavior that the context is not available when trying to get it with in a database call back.
note: The tenant info is set in the root level of request processing.

The tenant context is lost when trying to access the details within the database call back.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
adding the code here

```
//app.js
const express = require('express');
const httpContext = require('express-http-context');
const app = express();
const settingsController = require('./controller/settings')

app.use(httpContext.middleware);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    httpContext.ns.bindEmitter(req);
    httpContext.ns.bindEmitter(res);
    httpContext.set('tenant', 'falcon');
    next();
});

app.get('/api/v1/settings', settingsController.getSettings);


//SettingsController.js
const httpContext = require('express-http-context');

const mongodb = util.getDatabaseConnection();   
const getSettings = function (req, res) {
    const db = dataSource.getDb();
    console.log('Tenant id here ', httpContext.get('tenant')); //prints 'falcon'
    mongodb
        .collection('settings')
        .findOne({_id: req.param.id}, (err, doc) => {
            if(err) {
                //do more validations and other stuffs
                const tenant = httpContext.get('tenant'); //tenant is not available
                res.status(200).json({found: false});
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({found: true, data: docs});
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Difficult to say with the existing code. But have you read the troubleshooting [guide](https://github.com/skonves/express-http-context#troubleshooting). Does anything from there apply?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, indeed there are few open issues that the context is lost inside DB call back.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above issue in this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-express-multitenant
Shortly, I've used async local storage for that.